# Discord.js restricting command to a role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to restrict slash commands for it not to be viewable at all like using

```
.setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers);
```

but with roles instead of permissions like BanMemmbers

I searched all around about it but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of restricting it via slash commands, but you can use something like:

```js
if (!<ChatInputCommandInteraction>.inCachedGuild()) return;
const member = <ChatInputCommandInteraction>.member;

if (!member.roles.cache.has('role_id'))
  return <ChatInputCommandInteraction>.reply('You don\'t have that role!');
```